# DDD - Persistence outside the domain, how to name it?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I'm modeling my first DDD application and I caught stuck with this doubt...

In my application and infrastucture layers I have some details that need to be persisted, but, since these are not domain specific, I don't like to name it repositories. Someone can help me figure out how to name it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DDD and the Repository pattern (RP) are different things, it just happens that DDD makes use of RP. This means that you can wrap everything related to persistence in repositories, they just won't be Domain Repositories. Probably in your case you'd have PaymentGatewaysRepository or smth like that.

Point is, if you wrap persistence access details into a class so that the rest of the app doesn't care about storage, you're using the repository pattern no matter how you'll name that class.

Comment: Got it. Repository it is, so. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should elaborate some more... Why isn't it modeled? Is it only configuration settings, things outside of the scope of the model? Like logs, etc? Some names come to mind: Serialization, configuration, settings, etc.

Considering your comment, configuration settings are really orthogonal to a Domain Model, but payment gateway settings may or may not be outside of the model. Id depends on the kind of application you are writing. I believe that if you are writing a payment processor, then it is a bona fide "member of your" domain model :-) You can also model generic configurations in the model... imagine that your users will have their own overriden settings.. The config "model" could weakly reference the domain model...

You can also model these specifics in another domain entirely... a reusable domain model with its own persistence, and which could be used in different domains as an add-on...

Comment: Yes, something like this, or other like specific information about a payment gateway.